# Regex not capturing properly

Tags: php, regex

Here is a query I just want to build an array of parameters:

```
$subject = "SELECT * FROM a_table WHERE something='col1=:param1' AND col2=:param2 OR col3=:param3";
```

I tried:

```
$pattern = "^([\"'])(?:(?=(\\\\?))\\2.)*?\\1^"; 
$subject = preg_replace($pattern, "", $subject);
```

and

```
$pattern = '#[:][a-zA-Z0-9_]+#'; 
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches); 
print_r($matches);
```

Unfortunately I got only `param2` and `param3` as output

I would like my dump to look like this:

```
Array ( [0] => :param1 [1] => :param2 [2] => :param3 )
```

Comment: Consistency dude, consistency! You either use double quotes or single quotes. I would go for single quotes to prevent double escaping everything. Also using `^` as a delimiter in your first pattern isn't really cool. Your second expression [does work](http://regex101.com/r/yD4nU7). Basically I think you ripped those two expressions from the internet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply use this regex `=(:\w+)`

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM a_table WHERE something='col1=:param1' AND col2=:param2 OR col3=:param3";

preg_match_all('/=(:\w+)/', $query, $params, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($params[1]); $i++) {

    echo $params[1][$i]."\n";
}
```

***DEMO*** 
http://ideone.com/aut6q2

Comment: +1, but you don't need that loop.  `print_r($params[1]);` works just fine.

Comment: @AlanMoore Not if you want to do something with the values, tks anyway.

Comment: @AlPacino By myself and because i needed it! if you have time, check regexbuddy.com software, it's pretty handy and comes with lots of examples :)